# mosso versus gogrid which is better?

Tags: web-hosting, mosso, gogrid

I have reasonable experience to manage my own server, so gogrid style management is not a problem. But seems mosso is a tag cheaper somewhat- except the very difficult to access compute cycles terms. Anyone could share about this would be very welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, Mosso is just like a "reseller" hosting. They provide you everything whitelabel from billing to control panel then you sell it back to customers.

If you are developer, I recommend you choose GoGrid. Firstly, Mosso doesn't provide SSH access. Secondly, if you are RoR/Mongrel user, you are capped to limited RAM (unless you pay extra in addition to $100). Moreover, GoGrid allows you to choose server image (CentOS, Redhat, Windows) with some out-of-the-box support for RoR and LAMP.

Somemore, GoGrid provides you initial credits ($50 or $95 if you use MS-WEBFWRD) for you to try out before actually paying for it.

Comment: This answer is outdated. I strongly recommend everyone to stay away from GoGrid because currently they can't even provide you with constant internet connection. I am writing this after public network connection to our servers AGAIN went down (you can see my comment to Michael's post below). Imagine that - customers can't connect to your website because Internet connection of your hosting provider is down. And if you have second doubts, again, visit http://www.gogridstatus.com/ and see how much downtime they experience in a month.

Answer (score 3):

Well, even at the current moment as correct answer is marked GoGrid choice, I think I need to share my experience with GoGrid. 
It's been several weeks after we broke our commitment with them and I think I'm pretty calm now to write cons for them.

1) Images. We were trying to use Windows 2008 images and those were pretty old. To be up to date, you need to install 80+ updates and that takes a while. But that's not the worst thing. Worst thing is, that default image hdd size is 20gb and that was not enough to complete windows updating, at least in automatic way (not talking about installing additional software). There's no way to increase image size, so you need to make all kinds of workarounds (for example disable virtual memory, when installing).

2) Support. It's not fanatic. I would call it robotic. Although live chat is working, at least we were unable to solve by live chat most of the problems, because live chat support personel would always forward request to upper level, which is not accessible through live chat. Another thing is, that as I understood, engineers, that have real knowledge and access to infrastructure don't work at night and in weekends (I was working from Europe, so I had completely different time zone).

3) Service Level Agreement. You need to be careful about small print (for example I've missed that rule 1hour of non working is compensated 100x was working only for one month bill), but there are things, that are not mentioned - for example I was told, that SLA terms do not work for cloud storage, although I think you won't find this mentioned in SLA.

4) Reaction time. Although in SLA they say, that will solve any issue in two hours, we couldn't get solution in 10 days. Problem was clear: network speed between gogrid server instances, also between instance and cloud storage was 10-15kbps (measured using several tools, such as netio and etc., tested several instances and so on). That wasn't because they forgot or smth., we were checking status at various levels every day. My management talked with VP of technology or something and he promised that problem will be solved in nearest time, several days passed and no solution was proposed. And some of the emails about how they are investigating problem made me laugh.

5) Internet speeds. Sometimes they were really good (I've measured 550mbps download speed), but sometimes they are terrible (upload up to 0.05mbps).

If someone thinks, that this is some kind of competitors posting, I have chat and email logs about mentioned issues, also screen shots of internet speed tests and could provide under request.

Ok, and one good thing about their service - you can use several IP addresses on one instance (what our current hosting provider - Amazon EC2 is unable to do).

Answer (score 3):

Stay away from GoGrid !

I don't have any experience with Mosso, but I do have (unfortunately) VERY bad experience with GoGrid.

As other people mentioned, their support is horrible. Most times you will get a live chat person that really is no help at all - doesn't really know their system or how it works so he can't really help with any problem beyond restarting your server.

Another issue is their performance which is at best unreliable and at worst just not there. Starting from I/O which can drop to < 1mb/s (measured by a few tools) - ranging to network connections that are very slow - load balancers which do not spread the load (2 servers on RoundRobin get 70/30)

Not to mention a very buggy portal  - new server picks a free ip, which I am then told is in use...and not by me - even though I have the whole range "assigned" to me -
new cases which are saved without the text - buttons which say "upgrade to a new plan" but do nothing... etc... etc...

Their billing department which is not responsive and you have to argue about everything (why am I paying $0.5/gb traffic when the site states $0.29 ?????)

I have been using them for about a year now - and that's only because I don't have the time to move. Hopefully I will be able to get the hell out of there in a month.

As you can tell, I am very very frustrated with them. I know it's my fault I didn't run away sooner, but I really didn't expect such a low level of service and quality.

beware....

Yoav.

Answer (score 2):

Mosso has way better service though, and the clients stay happy. The only issue I have experienced with them ever was installing DNN (which is a pain period) and a single client machine refused to allow for FTP access to their site... but again, Mosso techs did everything they could to get it going.

Answer (score 0):

Mosso does not give you Admin control over the "servers" anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: I am the Technology Evangelist for GoGrid.

I wanted to address some of the points above by @Giedrius and @Yoav. I'm sorry if your experience was lower than expected. We have and continue to make dramatic improvements and upgrades to both our product features as well as our service. That being said, I want to answer a few points that you listed above, specifically:

1) **Images** - Do note that the HD size (persistent storage) is tied to the RAM allocation. Our base images for the lowest RAM allocation (512 MB) is now 30 GBs. Also, because some users experienced some performance issues with low allocations of RAM on Windows servers, we have set a minimum allocation of 1 GB or higher for most Windows instances. Also, all of our Windows 2008 instances now have SP2 on them: wiki.gogrid.com/wiki/index.php/Server_Images#Windows_2008_Server

2) **Support** - We are always working on making our support team and processes even better. Remember that there are several public clouds that charge for support, something we don't do. Yes, it is available 24/7/365 and you are correct that there are typically more support personnel available during business hours (that is the norm for many companies). Be we are here to help 24x7. Also, every GoGrid account gets a dedicated service team which consists of a variety of personnel from our organization (acct mgmt, tech support, billing, etc.)

3) **SLA** - We offer one of the most robust SLAs in the marketplace. Also, Cloud Storage IS in fact covered in our SLA under Section VI here: www.gogrid.com/legal/sla.php .

4) **Reaction time** - I do not believe that we ever state in the SLA that any issue will be "resolved" within 2 hours. I doubt that ANY hosting provider can offer that, simply because of the nature of hosting and the complexity therein. We will acknowledge and respond to tickets (as stated within the SLA) within 2 hours or 30 minutes depending on the nature of the ticket. I'm sorry if that isn't clear so please let me know where it can be better explained.

5) **Internet speeds** - we have multiple bandwidth providers for our datacenter. It is not typical that there is latency, jitter or slow transfer speeds. If a situation is encountered where the speeds are not what you expect, I encourage you to open a support ticket so that we can investigate.

6) **I/O** - recently we have been benchmarked by an independent 3rd party, CloudHarmony.com, as having the best I/O of cloud providers: http://blog.cloudharmony.com/2010/06/disk-io-benchmarking-in-cloud.html

7) **Network Connections** - see #5 above

8) **Load Balancers** - if you are encountering balancing issues, we encourage you to report it. Details on our LB can be found on the wiki: wiki.gogrid.com/wiki/index.php/(F5)_Load_Balancer

9) **Portal** - We continue to make optimizations to the web portal including recently launching a "list view" for customers with larger environments. If the portal is "misbehaving", I recommend clearing your cache and using the latest browser version (I personally use Chrome and Firefox regularly on the portal w/o issue). Alternatively, you could use the API to manage your GoGrid infrastructure.

10) **Transfer Plan** - A few months ago, we released some new RAM and Transfer Plans. It seems that you are still on the old Transfer plan if you have $0.50/GB instead of $0.29. We don't automatically change customers' plans without their permission. So I recommend that you upgrade your plan to enjoy the new pricing.

Hope that helps answer the questions/concerns. I didn't mean for it to be a sales pitch (as I'm not a sales guy) but I wanted to be sure that other readers had "the other side of the story."

Please contact me should you have any questions: michael[at]gogrid.com

Thanks!
-Michael

Comment: This answer is pure crap (I did try to contact Michael - once he responded with some generic "we'll look into it"; other time he didn't respond at all). I'm using GoGrid and I've spent last two days awake almost 24h per day trying to keep site online because of their problems with LAN. Imagine that - hosting company that's can't keep their own LAN running - they currently have ~10 downtime incidents per month -> http://www.gogridstatus.com/ ...