# GoGrid Customer Review / Satisfaction

Tags: gogrid

Has anyone used GoGrid's cloud hosting and if so, what were your experiences?  Did you find it performant and cost effective?

Comment: This would be a question better suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote some about this in this thread: [mosso versus gogrid which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188245/mosso-versus-gogrid-which-is-better/2682695#2682695)